# Query "is valid" but produces an error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This query “is valid” according to the BigQuery SQL editor. However when it is run, it produces an error:Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Input:

```
SELECT 
  (Select 
     pcr.repdte 
     from 
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_
     Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR) as Quarter,
(SELECT 
     Round(PCR.lnlsdepr) 
     FROM 
   usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Performance_
   and_Condition_Ratios as PCR) as NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
(SELECT LD.IDdepsam 
    FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_
      Deposits_Based_on_the_dollar250_000_Reporting_Threshold 
      AS LD) as DepositAccountsWithMoreThan250k
```

Output 
Scalar subquery produced more than one element

[image]

The output of the queries when they are run independently is below:

```
SELECT
  PCR.repdte as quarter
  FROM 
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_
     Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR
```

Output: 
[image]

```
SELECT 
  Round(PCR.lnlsdepr) as NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits
  FROM 
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_
     Performance_and_Condition_Ratios as PCR
```

Output: 
[image]

```
SELECT LD.IDdepsam as DepositAccountsWithMoreThan250k
  FROM 
    usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_
    19921231_Deposits_Based_on_the_dollar250_000_
     Reporting_Threshold AS LD
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: If your queries like you have produce more than one row of data you can not select the data like this,it must only produce one row of data.  So individually they are fine, and when you check if its valid, it is.  If they only returned 1 row/set of data each it would be fine, but they return more so you get failure.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar subqueries cannot produce more than a **single row**. You are showing your scalar subqueries show a *single column*, and **multiple rows**. That -- by definition -- won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by not using a subquery, and instead using JOIN

```
SELECT 
  pcr.cert as cert,
  pcr.name as NameOfBank,
  pcr.repdte as Quarter, 
  Round(PCR.lnlsdepr) as NetLoansAndLeasesToDeposits,
  LD.IDdepsam as DepositAccountsWithMoreThan250k
FROM 
    usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Performance
    _and_Condition_Ratios as PCR
JOIN
    usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Deposits_Based_
    on_the_dollar250_000_Reporting_Threshold AS LD
ON PCR.cert = LD.cert
```

Output: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix, use `ARRAY`.

For example, this query works:

```
 SELECT 1 x, (SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("1")) y) y
```

[image]

But this one will give you the stated error:

```
 SELECT 1 x, (SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("1,2")) y) y

 "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"
```

And I can fix it with `ARRAY()`, that will produce nested repeated results:

```
 SELECT 1 x, ARRAY(SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("1,2")) y) y
```

[image]

Or make sure to emit only one row, with `LIMIT`:

```
 SELECT 1 x, (SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("1,2")) y LIMIT 1) y
```

[image]